# MATLAB: Blanked Plots when Looping on a Multidimensional Array

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, plot

My goal output is to have four plots displaying (time, dist_a),  (time, speed_a), (time, dist_b), and (time, speed_b) when looping through a multidimensional array.  However, I am displaying only 2 blanked plots.

Here is my code:

```
time = rand(10, 1)
dist_a = rand(10,1)
dist_b = rand(10,1)
speed_a = rand(10,1)
speed_b = rand(10,1)

dist = cat(2, dist_a, dist_b);
speed = cat(2, speed_a, speed_b);

for k = 1:2
figure;
plot(time, dist(k));
plot(time, speed(k));
end
```

Comment: try `plot(time, dist(:,k)); plot(time, speed(:,k));`. `dist(k)` only gives you the k-th element in the matrix.

Comment: Also the 2nd plot will overwrite the first. Add `hold on` somewhere between `figure` and the 2nd `plot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems were two-fold. Firstly, you were only plotting a single point as opposed to a vector, changing `dist(k)` to `dist(:,k)` for example fixes this. Secondly, if you want four figures with a loop that executes twice, you need to include another `figure` command before the second plot. The following should do what you asked for, I also added in some formatting to make the plots looks nicer

```
for k = 1:2
    figure
    plot(time, dist(:,k),'o','LineWidth',2);
    xlabel('time')
    ylabel('distance')
    box on
    grid on

    figure
    plot(time, speed(:,k),'o','LineWidth',2);
    xlabel('time')
    ylabel('speed')
    box on
    grid on
end
```

which gives:

[image]